# Can't create a NeighborLoader for HeteroData: 'EdgeStorage' object has no attribute 'num_nodes'

Tags: machine-learning, graph, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a NeighborLoader for my data.

```
AttributeError: 'EdgeStorage' object has no attribute 'num_nodes'
```

I load up my graph and split it into training / test / validation using RandomNodeSplit, then, I try and pass the split data into the NeighborLoader and get the error above.

**Code used:**

```
data = torch.load(training_config['data_file'])
targets = pd.read_pickle(training_config['targets_file'])
print(type(data))

# CREATING THE TRAIN, TEST AND VAL MASKS
split = T.RandomNodeSplit(num_val=training_config['validation_split'], num_test=training_config['test_split'])
data_split = split(data)
data_split.num_nodes = data.num_nodes
print(data_split)
print(type(data_split))
sampler = ImbalancedSampler(data_split['word'].y, input_nodes=data_split['word'].train_mask)

loader = NeighborLoader(
    data_split,
    num_neighbors=[10] * 2,
    batch_size=training_config['batch_size'],
    input_nodes=data_split['word'].train_mask,
    sampler=sampler
)
```

And here's the result from those print statements:

```
<class 'torch_geometric.data.hetero_data.HeteroData'>

HeteroData(
  num_classes=2,
  num_nodes=59565,
  word={
    y=[39566],
    x=[39566, 2],
    train_mask=[39566],
    val_mask=[39566],
    test_mask=[39566],
  },
  sentence={ x=[19999, 1] },
  (word, depGraph, word)={ edge_index=[2, 934] },
  (word, head, word)={ edge_index=[2, 934] },
  (word, previousWord, word)={ edge_index=[2, 842] },
  (word, fromSentence, sentence)={ edge_index=[2, 574] },
  (word, nextWord, word)={ edge_index=[2, 842] },
  (word, pos, pos)={ edge_index=[2, 39566] },
  (word, edge, edge)={ edge_index=[2, 39566] },
  (word, feat_aspect, feat_aspect)={ edge_index=[2, 1318] },
  (word, feat_case, feat_case)={ edge_index=[2, 1251] },
  (word, feat_conjtype, feat_conjtype)={ edge_index=[2, 708] },
  (word, feat_definite, feat_definite)={ edge_index=[2, 5349] },
  (word, feat_degree, feat_degree)={ edge_index=[2, 2735] },
  (word, feat_foreign, feat_foreign)={ edge_index=[2, 19] },
  (word, feat_gender, feat_gender)={ edge_index=[2, 169] },
  (word, feat_mood, feat_mood)={ edge_index=[2, 307] },
  (word, feat_number, feat_number)={ edge_index=[2, 14435] },
  (word, feat_numtype, feat_numtype)={ edge_index=[2, 1588] },
  (word, feat_person, feat_person)={ edge_index=[2, 1713] },
  (word, feat_polarity, feat_polarity)={ edge_index=[2, 35] },
  (word, feat_poss, feat_poss)={ edge_index=[2, 142] },
  (word, feat_prontype, feat_prontype)={ edge_index=[2, 7914] },
  (word, feat_punctside, feat_punctside)={ edge_index=[2, 1344] },
  (word, feat_puncttype, feat_puncttype)={ edge_index=[2, 3603] },
  (word, feat_tense, feat_tense)={ edge_index=[2, 1895] },
  (word, feat_verbform, feat_verbform)={ edge_index=[2, 2457] },
  (sentence, nextSentence, sentence)={ edge_index=[2, 39996] }
)

<class 'torch_geometric.data.hetero_data.HeteroData'>
```

**Full Error Trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/PyTorchConvert.py", line 117, in <module>
    loader = NeighborLoader(
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/graph_builder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/loader/neighbor_loader.py", line 229, in __init__
    neighbor_sampler = NeighborSampler(
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/graph_builder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/sampler/neighbor_sampler.py", line 101, in __init__
    colptr_dict, row_dict, self.perm = to_hetero_csc(
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/graph_builder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/sampler/utils.py", line 101, in to_hetero_csc
    out = to_csc(store, device, share_memory, is_sorted, src_node_time)
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/graph_builder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/sampler/utils.py", line 66, in to_csc
    colptr = index2ptr(col, data.size(1))
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/graph_builder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/storage.py", line 489, in size
    self._parent()[self._key[-1]].num_nodes)
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/graph_builder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/storage.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'EdgeStorage' object has no attribute 'num_nodes'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So the types are HeteroData, however, NeighborLoader is getting an EdgeStorage somewhere and I can't use it to batch my data? Are there any fixes or alternatives that I could try to this?

I am able to train a SageConv without batching, however, I'd like to try it and see how it affects my results.

Comment: Where exactly? Please edit & update your question to include the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: You're right, completely forgot to post the full error trace. Sorry! Should be added now.

Comment: I am afraid the line producing the error cannot be seen in the code you have posted.

Comment: It's the NeighborLoader call. I tried something else and changed the variable name and didn't notice the difference in the error to what I posted earlier. Edited it already. 

Rest of the stack errors are pytorch geometric internals.